# javascript onclick changes styles

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick, var

i have little animation with picture, i want to change cursor to default ( on picture ), after animation start, if you try my animation, you will see that after onclick function you still have cursor: pointer on pic. but i want there to be default after animation.

my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1u6kbz7q/

HTML

```
                            <div id="facebook_text">
                                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/rostislav.danko" alt="facebook" target="_blank">Odkaz</a>
                            </div>
                            <div id="facebook_image">
                                <img class="facebook_animation" src="facebook.jpg"></img>
                            </div>
                        <script src="facebook_animation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

CSS

```
#facebook_text {
    display: none;
}
#facebook_text a {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-top: 35px;
    z-index: 1;
}
#facebook_text a:hover {
    color: #e5e500;
}
#facebook_image.fly {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 125px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    transition: ease-in-out 1s;
}
#facebook_image img {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;    
    height: 35px;
    width: 35px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    transition: ease-in-out 1s;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

javascript

```
document.querySelector('.facebook_animation').onclick=function() {
        var d = document.getElementById("facebook_image");
        d.className = d.className + " fly";
            d.style.cursor = 'default';
        var t = document.getElementById("facebook_text");
        var delayed = setTimeout(function() {
            t.style.display = 'block';
        }, 500);
    }
```

Comment: Your worked with `facebook_image` instead `facebook_animation` http://jsfiddle.net/1u6kbz7q/5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to involve JS on that *cursor* matter: http://jsfiddle.net/1u6kbz7q/3/
you're already adding the `.fly`, so simply target the .fly's image in CSS

```
#facebook_image.fly img{
    cursor: default;
}
```

also `<img>` is a self-closing tag. no need to use the closing `</img>`